# making classes public for several projects

Tags: actionscript-3, actionscript

We are busy making plugins for several plugins. 
These are all seperate projects. We have written a custom class that handles all the logging of the plugins. This is the same over all projects.

Would it be possible that we can put the logging class in a separate folder that is know over all projects and that will automaticly be added to the projects when its being compiled?

That way we dont have to copy the file in each project and change the paths etc everytime.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You're making plugins for plugins? I don't understand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you'd like to avoid compiling a separate swc library and would prefer to use your source (.as) files as a library, then what you'll have to do is reference the folder containing your library (your .as files) from inside your IDE. This process will differ among IDEs but, for example

- In Flash Professional CS5, open the project you'd like to work on and go to File > Publish Settings > Flash tab > ActionScript 3.0 settings > Source Path tab. Then add your library path in the list labeled 'Folders containing actionScript class files'. Alternatively you can make the library accessible to all projects by including the path in Edit > Preferences > ActionScript > ActionScript 3.0 settings. This way you won't have to tweak each projects publish settings.
- In Flash Builder 4, open the project you'd like to work on and go to Project > Properties > ActionScript Build Path > Source path tab. Then add your library path in the list labeled 'Aditional source folders outside the main source folder'.

And you're done. You can then reference the logging class from anywhere inside your projects, provided that you insert the appropriate 'import' statement at the top of the .as file you're working on.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot add a folder automatically to a project when you build it, it has to be referenced in advance, otherwise code completion, for instance, wouldn't work.

You can make a Library Project (.swc) which contains the global file(s) and add that project to each of the modules' **build path**. You can do this by right-clicking a module, selection Properties and under Build Path, add a project reference to your library.

Have a great day!

Comment: As stated here best bet is probably compile the Logger into a swc, include the swc as a dependency, another option is adding the shared path to the compiler args/project properties, but really it's a bad plan since down the road that configuration needs to be re-called, at least with a swc it's simply a matter of adding an import (and can be automated with maven or other build/project management tools)